# iOS depth buffer write possible?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I have a complex pre-rendered scene which I would like to use as a backdrop in a 3D iPad game which uses a static camera.

For each frame redraw the screen will be erased to this background. The part I do not know how to do is set the depth buffer to the one stored in this pre-rendered image, so that dynamic 3D objects will respect the depth information in said image.

Is there any way to achieve this on an iPad, using opengl es 2.0?

I looked into several approaches, but could not find anything suitable so far.